# Automate a task of editing cdr files in c# using corel draw type library

Tags: svg, reflection, shapes, coreldraw, cdr

Update :
I am able to get the shapes now,
only insertion of texts is remaining, and I am not able to figure out the way to insert text.
Now I am getting an exception while creating the instance of the shape class :

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A77D0076-C6D1-4D32-9F72-F3A62CE56578} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'**

I have nearly 200 cdr files with some shapes containing in it  also I have a list of names. Shapes can be nested like rectangle inside rectangle.
I want to generate a new copy of that file with a name from the list in each of the group of shapes(text should be in innermost shape).
Then I have to save that file as svg.

here is what i have tried so far but I am not able to get a way what to do after this.

I used the Coreldraw type library and I am able to open the cdr file but I am not able to figure out which property of the document in corelDraw I should look to get the shapes.
previous questions also did not help me.

```
Type pia_type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CorelDRAW.Application");Application app = Activator.CreateInstance(pia_type) as Application;
app.Visible = true;
Document document = app.OpenDocument(@"Path_To_Cdr");

// Update : 
ShapeRange shapes = document.ActivePage.Shapes.FindShapes();   
foreach(Shape s in shapes)
{
       // this is giving exception 
       // System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component 
       Shape newShape = new Shape()
       {
           // Text.Contents = "Eureka!!"
       };
       s.PlaceTextInside(newShape);  
}
```

Comment: Frankly, I'm not familiar with corel draw's internal object model. But I doubt it allows to actually nest geometry or text elements into another one. The common concept is to stack elements on each other - so a text element aligned "within" e.g. a rectangle is in fact on top of this rectangle but placed according to the referenced element's boundary coordinates (x, y, width, height). bonus630's example makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah ,
I also did something similar,
VGCore.Shape textShape = document.ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText(
                            centerX, centerY, "Eureka", cdrTextLanguage.cdrLanguageMixed,
                            cdrTextCharSet.cdrCharSetMixed, fontName, fontSize,
                            cdrTriState.cdrUndefined, cdrTriState.cdrUndefined,
                            cdrFontLine.cdrMixedFontLine, cdrAlignment.cdrCenterAlignment
                            );

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Shape newShape = s.Layer.CreateArtisticText(s.LeftX, s.CenterY, "Eureka");
```